# Passing multiple onClick parameters using div.innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

I want to pass multiple parameters to a function that is called via onClick. Here is the code:

```
 div.innerHTML += '<input type="button" name="back" id="back" value="Back" onClick="homeForm(\'' + form,divName + '\')" />';

function homeForm(form,divName){
//do something   

}
```

This works with one parameter but not two:

```
 div.innerHTML += '<input type="button" name="back" id="back" value="Back" onClick="homeForm(\'' + form + '\')" />';
```

Could someone post a working method for this, or perhaps a cleaner way?

Comment: Try `'onClick="homeForm(\'' + form,divName + '\')"'` in the console and see what happens. Then work from there. If you want to learn how to properly bind event handlers, have a look at http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html

Comment: Thanks Felix. That site looks pretty informative. I will check it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So in the end this code was the only one that worked for me. I'm posting it here in case someone else needs it:

```
 div.innerHTML += '<input type="button" name="back" id="back" value="Back"    onClick="homeForm(\''+myForm+'\',\''+divName+'\')" />';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below,  Don't escape it. Concatenate params properly. like below:

```
div.innerHTML += '<input type="button" name="back" id="back" value="Back" onClick="homeForm(' + form  + ',' + divName + ')" />';
```

Answer (score 1):

I can see from your question , you wish to pass from and div in onclick function,
So, very easy way is that you passed id of both, and get value of that from function,
it will be easy to handle and evaluate.

```
div.innerHTML += '<input type="button" name="back" id="back" value="Back" onClick=\'homeForm("formId","divId")\' />';

function homeForm(formId,divId)
{
       console.log($("#"+formId));
       console.log($("#"+divId));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy!  It looks like you have forgotten that the comma between form and divName should be enclosed in quotes.  Instead of

```
...' + form,divName + '...
```

do

```
...' + form + ',' + divName + '...
```